# CATALINA_HOME and Maven + LOG4J

Tags: maven, log4j

I have this line in log4j:

**log4j.appender.FILE.File=${catalina.home}/logs/debug.log**

Works perfectly when I run the project from IntelliJ.

But when I try to run a TestNG test (from maven) it fails:

**log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /logs/debug.log (No such file or directory)**

I could hardcode the path and all will be good. But I don't want that solution since I can deploy on various systems where ${catalina.home} is in different place.

I develop on a mac and deploy on freebsd and centos. Tomcat is in different places all the time. I could use /var/log/myapp.log but ...

Is any way to define a common variable (available in IntelliJ and when I run the maven test) with the log file path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to use [the Maven Profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) which will be activated when the `${env.catalina.home}` is not existed, together with the [Maven Surefire Plugin:Using System Properties](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html).

```
<profile>
   <id>mock-catalina-home</id>
   <activation>
      <property>
         <name>!env.catalina.home</name>
      </property>
   </activation>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.14</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <property>
                            <name>catalina.home</name>
                            <value>PATH_TO_CATALINA_HOME</value>
                        </property>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Please note that the `PATH_TO_CATALINA_HOME` can be referred by [the Maven Properties](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html) as well. e.g.

```
<systemProperties>
    <property>
        <name>PATH_TO_CATALINA_HOME</name>
        <value>${my.dev.catalina.home}</value>
    </property>
</systemProperties>
```

This will help us to define the `${my.dev.catalina.home}` to be various values.

I hope this may help.

Answer (score 2):

In order for the log4j properties file get the correct value for ${catalina.home} when running the tests from maven, it needs to be in a file that is filtered by maven (src/main/resources is a directory for files like that). Also, the variable 'catalina.home' needs to be setup in maven. You can create a variable AKA maven property that uses an environment variable so you can define the different location for the tomcat install on each machine:

```
<properties>
  <catalina.home>${env.catalina.home}</catalina.home>
<properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify the location of the log files in relation to the home directory for your user account.

In log4j this would use the following format: ${user.home}/weblogs/log4j1.log

In log4j 2, this would use the following format: ${sys:user.home}/weblogs/log4j2Rolling.log

log4j 2 can use the Java system properties, environmental variables, or Maven properties